# Why am I getting java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated?

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to download imags from a url and then decode them.
The problem is that I don't know how large are they and if I decode them right away, the app crashes with too-big images.

I'm doing the following and it works with most of the images but with some of them, it throws the `java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated` exception.
It's not a matter of size because it happens with a 75KB or a 120KB image and not with a 20MB or 45KB image.
Also the format is not important as it can happen either with a jpg or png image.

`pis` is an `InputStream`.

```
    Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(pis);
    bis.mark(1024 * 1024);
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmImg=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis,null,opts);

    Log.e("optwidth",opts.outWidth+"");
    try {
        bis.reset();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        int ratio = opts.outWidth/800; 
        Log.e("ratio",String.valueOf(ratio));
        if (opts.outWidth>=800)opts.inSampleSize = ratio;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis,null,opts);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to decode large image. I did it by selecting gallery image.

```
File photos= new File("imageFilePath that you select");
Bitmap b = decodeFile(photos);
```

"decodeFile(photos)" function is used for decode large image. I think you need to get image .png or .jpg formet.

```
 private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

you can display it by using imageView.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sdcardimage);
img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: But how can I pass the InputStream that contains the info to be converted into a Bitmap?¿

Comment: @sergi this is the best way to do it. You have an InputStream and `decodeStream()` takes an input stream param.

Comment: Now I've got it working this way but wanted to see which was the best way to do it..

Comment: Problem is that original question looks that author wanted to decode just stream. I have the same problem, but I can't use File() to open stream 2 times, because I'm downloading data from the Internet. Images are alway smaller like 400kB. So I'm using BufferedInputStreamand and reset() to read it twice.